# How can I export my joomla website media?

Tags: content, media-manager

I am closing down my website which has a large archive of photos and video in the media section and want to be able to a copy of the photos and videos and put them into DropBox or such. Is there a quick and easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say keep things very simply by:

Going to the File Manager via your hosting control panel and zip up the folder inside the **media** directory that contains your assets. Or possibly have 2 separate zip files for images and videos. Whatever suits you best.

If your host does not provide you wish a File Manager, then you can download the folder to your computer via FTP instead, but will be a little slower.

Once done, simply upload the zip file to Dropdown.

I would say this is quicker than using any dropbox component for Joomla

Hope this helps